# Convert file to Base64 then send through P2P between 2 Android Devices

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build an file sharing app using p2p connection but  I don't know how to send the file. I'm done with the host/client connection and really need help with the file sending part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will always be better if you share some code along with the question, so that we know what you told is what you wanted. Since you did not, I am going to guess that you have every other piece setup properly.

1. Set up the socket between Client and Server (Sender and Receiver)
2. Open the OutputStream from the Client / Sender
3. Open the file that you want to send. Use an InputStream.
4. Read the inputstream (byte by byte) and write to outputstream ( this sends the data via the socket to the Receiver)
5. Once the file has been successfully read (all the bytes of it), flush the outputstream.

There are many code examples in google, here is one I could find easily.

[GitHub P2P Example](https://github.com/YaphetS1/WiFi-Direct-File-Transfer-App/blob/release/test/app/src/main/java/com/app/wi_fi_direct/servers/TransferData.java)

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy. You must go for

- Learn how to establish a TCP server/client flow.
- Possibly learn how to    use UDP broadcasting to autodiscover
  targets.

This [example](https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/03/27/incorporating-socket-programming-into-your-applications/) may help you .